# Differentiation of a scalar w.r.t. a matrix when both are functions of same vector

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

There is a scalar $s$ defined

$$s=v^Tx$$

Where the elements of vector $v$ are defined

$$v_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

Assume these first derivatives are not constants, so that each element $v_i$ is a function of the element $x_i$ (but independent of the other elements $x_{k\neq i}$).

And there is a (covariance) matrix $\Sigma$ each of whose $[i,j]$ elements are functions of $x_i$ and $x_j$ (but independent of the other elements $x_{k\neq i,j}$).

$$\sigma_{ij} = g(x_i, x_j)$$

What is $\frac{\partial s}{\partial \Sigma}$?

I'm thinking it is not zero because of the chain rule. This is what I came up with:

$$\left[\frac{\partial s}{\partial \Sigma}\right]_{ij}=\frac{\partial s}{\partial \sigma_{ij}}=\frac{\partial s}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \sigma_{ij}}+\frac{\partial s}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial \sigma_{ij}}$$

Is that right?

EDIT:

Oh, found this (133 in the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)):

$$\frac{\partial s}{\partial \sigma_{ij}}=tr \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial \Sigma}^T\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \sigma_{ij}} \right)$$

Not sure if it's the answer, but helps.

Comment: Is $g$ a fixed function? Or do you just mean that each $\sigma_{ij}$ is *some* function of $x_i$ and $x_j$?

Comment: Either way, it is not entirely clear what $\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial \sigma_{ij}}$ would mean. Partial differentials are defined for coordinate systems - sets of independent variables capable of completely identifying the points in the domain. In an $n$-dimensional space, it requires exactly $n$ independent variables to have a coordinate system. Any additional variables cannot be independent. Their value would depend on the other $n$. Since you say $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, it presumably is symmetric, but this still leaves $n \choose 2$ different $\sigma_{ij}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair 1) Yes g is a fixed function. 2) Well, each $(i,j)$ element of the covariance matrix is dependent only upon $x_i, x_j$ (and not on $x_{k \neq i,j}$), and all the $x_i$ are independent of each other, so that there isn't really any difference between partial and full derivative of $\sigma_{ij}$ w.r.t. $x_i$ or $x_j$.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as the "full derivative" when there is more than one variable. But in any case, I said *nothing* about partial derivatves of $\sigma_{ij}$ with respect to $x_k$ for any $k$. Those are defined (for every $k$, even the ones it doesn't depend on). But you have not made any use of those. It is the partial derivatives of $x_k$ with respect to $\sigma_{ij}$ which you have made use of, but which are not well defined.

Comment: @PaulSinclair If $\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_i} = q(x_i; x_j)$ is well defined, and we know that $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}=0$, then doesn't it follow that $\frac{\partial \partial x_i}{\sigma_{ij}} = \frac{1}{q(x_i; x_j)}$ (by a simple application of the chain rule)?

Comment: Partial derivatives are different from regular derivatives. The chain rule in this case would say $$\frac {\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{k,\ell} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \sigma_{k\ell}} \frac{\partial \sigma_{k\ell}}{\partial x_j}$$where $k,\ell$ vary over *whichever $n$ elements of $\Sigma$ you pick to form your $n$-dimensional coordinate system*. Even if there were only $n$ of the $\sigma_{ij}$ in the first place, it would still *not* follow that $$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \sigma_{k\ell}} = \frac 1{\dfrac {\partial \sigma_{k\ell}}{\partial x_i}}$$